# GitLab private runner stuck on npm install

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, gitlab, npm-install, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to set up a CI pipeline on GitLab.com using a private runner instead of a shared one. The project uses Node, so I'm using a `node:6` image.

The `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
image: node:6

stages:
    - test

javascript_tests:
    stage: test
    script:
        - npm install
        - npm run test:unit
    when: always
```

The runner stays on "running" stage for about 30 minutes and only then started to output something relevant:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed 
http://10.252.156.164:4880/@types%2fjsforce/-/jsforce-1.9.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.252.156.164:4880
```

What can I do to solve this? I thought that installing `gitlab-runner` on a DigitalOcean droplet would be the only things to worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `node:6` with `node:latest` fixed this problem.