# "npm install" fails with ECONNREFUSED while building Docker image

Tags: docker, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to build a Docker image that contains NPM and installs some tools, but when I issue the install command, as in:

```
RUN npm install -g sfdx-cli
```

The build hangs for a while, and then a lot of errors are thrown. And it is the same error:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed http://10.252.156.164:4880/@babel%2fcode-frame/-/code-frame-7.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.252.156.164:4880
```

Every other resource I find on the web by searching this error results in an answer/article about using NPM behind a proxy, but that is not the case here. I'm not behind a proxy.

What can I do to make this error stop?

---

Running `RUN echo "${http_proxy}" && echo "${HTTP_PROXY}"` in my Dockerfile while building I get the following output:

```
Step 8/16 : RUN echo "${http_proxy}" && echo "${HTTP_PROXY}"
 ---> Running in 09bfc89592ae


Removing intermediate container 09bfc89592ae
```

Comment: What's interesting is this address -> http://10.252.156.164:4880. From my understanding, that is not the default address that NPM will be using to obtain modules. Are you using a custom built Docker image to run these commands and is this IP address on the same network you are running your computer on?

Comment: I'm using the `ubuntu:latest` base image in my Dockerfile. That address is not part of my network. I don't know why NPM is pointing to that address either.

Comment: Can you add `RUN echo "${http_proxy}" && echo "${HTTP_PROXY}"` to your docker image and post the output?

Comment: Sure. I edited my original post with the output.

Comment: Not the answer, but can you edit your npm install command to this:

`npm install -g https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-cli/channels/stable/sfdx-cli-v7.8.1-8f830784cc-darwin-x64.tar.xz`

That is the latest version of that module and will force NPM to use a different URL to get it.

Comment: I don't have just sfdx to install though. A couple more stuff I would like to be installed with npm. :)

Comment: I remember having a similar issue when using an older version of Node with a GitLab build (here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55906917/2350986). So bumping the Node version might actually help, I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to build the docker image successfully, here is my Dockerfile,

```
FROM alpine:3.8
RUN apk add --no-cache nodejs npm
RUN npm install -g sfdx-cli
```

[image]

If you do not want to alpine as a base image then share your Dockerfile.

Or also you can run `RUN  npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.com/`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try to use an alpine image instead of an Ubuntu image today. I searched a bit about Alpine and it seems a really good base image for containers due to its small size. :) I'll let you know if this works.

Answer (score 2):

Try `docker build . --network="host"`

(Ref: https://github.com/verdaccio/docker-examples/issues/33)